# Video Slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I am trying to figure out why my "Back" Button is not working properly. It seems like the only thing im doing wrong is writing the function for previousSlide. Hoping someone can help. See my code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {



 $(function(){
     var counter = 0;
     var videos = [
         {videoURL: 'media/SLIDE1.mp4'},
         {videoURL: 'media/SLIDE2.mp4'},
         {videoURL: 'media/SLIDE3.mp4'},
         {videoURL: 'media/SLIDE4.mp4'},
         {videoURL: 'media/SLIDE5.mp4'},
         {videoURL: 'media/SLIDE6.mp4'},
         {videoURL: 'media/SLIDE7.mp4'},
         {videoURL: 'media/SLIDE8.mp4'},
         {videoURL: 'media/SLIDE9.mp4'}
     ]; 

     $('#next').click(updateSlide);

     function updateSlide() { 
         console.log(counter);
                  console.log(videos[counter]);
       $('video').attr('src', videos[counter].videoURL);

       if (counter < videos.length - 1) {
          counter++;
       } else {
        counter = 0;
       }

       //if you leave this uncommented it always increments counter, regardless of what you did above
       //counter++;

     }

     $('#previous').click(previousSlide);


     function previousSlide() { 
         console.log(counter);
                  console.log(videos[counter]);
       $('video').attr('src', videos[counter].videoURL);

       if (counter > 0) {
          counter--;
       } else {
        counter = 0;
       }
     }


     //Enables Left and Right Key Navigation
     $(document).keydown(function(e){

        if ( e.which === 37 ) { //left

            $('#previous').click(); 

        } else if ( e.which === 39 ) { //right

            $('#next').click();
    }
  });

});
```

Thanks for your help!

Adam

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {  });` does the same thing as `$(function(){  });` - there's no need to nest them

Comment: thanks Ian. Any ideas on the back button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decrement before:

```
  function previousSlide() { 
      if (counter > 0) {
         counter--;
      } else {
         counter = 0;
      }

      $('video').attr('src', videos[counter].videoURL);

 }
```

Do something similar for your `updateSlide` function (increment before) and you should be all set.  Seems like it's just an off-by-one error.

```
 function updateSlide() { 
    console.log(counter);
    console.log(videos[counter]);

    if (counter < videos.length - 1) {
      counter++;
    } else {
    counter = 0;
    }

    $('video').attr('src', videos[counter].videoURL);

}
```

Comment: Hi Kevin thanks for the response. I tried this solution but I still run into the same problem. If you click Next the counter goes up by 1. Then if I click Previous once the counter goes up by 1 again. However, if I press Previous several more times it will start going backwards properly. See the example on t-mrkt.com hover your mouse toward the bottom. Also monitor in the console log and you will see what i mean.

Comment: Adam, looking at your source code, I don't think you changed `updateSlide` the way that I suggested. I suggested that you update it in the same way you changed `previousSlide`. Please try that and let me know if it works!!

Comment: Hey Kevin, Sorry I only updated locally by mistake. check it out again.

Comment: Hey Anthony, my copy of http://t-mrkt.com/js/script.js still has that problem - check out my version of `updateSlide`, which I posted in the above answer.

Comment: Hey Kevin, I think it didnt update properly. So sorry but please check again. This time it should have what you posted above.

Comment: It seems to me that it's working fine now.  Try `console.log`ging at the end of your functions - you're `console.log`ging before you switch the source.

Comment: Hey Kevin, Sorry I am a newbie. Whats a Console.log ging? I looked at the site, t-mrkt.com and the back button doesnt function properly. if you press it one it actually advances the slide instead of sending it back. thanks again for your help!

Comment: That's `console.log`-ing, as in calling the function `console.log`.

Comment: oh ok. so If you take a look at the console.log you can see the array jump from one slide to the next [0],[1]. etc however, the first time you hit the previous slide button you will see that instead of going back to the previous slide it actually jumps ahead one slide. then if you press previous again it will in fact go back.  Hopefully I am explaining this correctly. But in a true slideshow, if you hit Previous it should take you back to the slide you came from... thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I will look at it when I get home.  Check my profile for my personal email and feel free to nudge me about it.

Comment: Hey Kevin thought I would nudge you in the forum because your email is not listed. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Adam, I still can't reproduce that behavior.  When I hit previous it goes to the current slide, which is appropriate, since it's the first slide.

Comment: Hey Kevin, I looked at it again and I think the console.log was throwing me off. perhaps i did something wrong printing to it. It appears to be working fine now. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Did you see my previous comment about that? "It seems to me that it's working fine now. Try console.logging at the end of your functions - you're console.logging before you switch the source. – Kevin Schmid May 29 at 18:27 " Glad you were able to resolve the issue!!!

Comment: Ahh ok. Kevin, I am having trouble interpreting can you show me what you mean by displaying a before and after of what the code looks like now and what it should look like? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you Kevin. You have been amazing. Any chance I can email you about one more thing I am trying to figure out?